# ¿A qué se refiere «volador» en Colombia?

Tags: vocabulario, hispanoamérica, colombia

Según [Spanishdict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/volador), «volador» puede ser una cometa (en Bolivia y Venezuela, dice) o puede ser un petardo.

Leí una historia que tiene lugar en Medellín y aquí por el contexto «volador» claramente se refiere a un petardo.

Pero tambien hay un cerro en la misma ciudad llamado El Volador y alguien me dijo que este lugar es para volar cometas. Entonces me pregunta a qué se refiere «volador». ¿Este lugar es realmente para lanzar petardos o para volar cometas?

¿Que quiere decir «volador» en Colombia?

Comment: La respuesta de @alvalongo es correcta. Yo vivo en Medellín y te puedo confirmar que el cerro "El volador" es para elevar cometas (que aquí NO se llaman voladores) porque igual el nombre hace referencia a "volar". En Medellín también se le dice volador a alguien muy astuto o inteligente. Ej. Ese niño es un volador en el colegio.

Comment: Video sobre el cerro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAMpLb-ZV8Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Colombia un **volador** es un dispositivo cilíndrico lleno de pólvora y que está adosado a un palo de material tipo madera muy ligero, que cuando se enciende vuela y al terminar su recorrido produce un ruido de explosión y en algunos casos un destello luminoso.

En la imagen anexa el hombre sostiene en su mano izquierda un **volador** el cual está encendiendo con la mano derecha.

Se aclara que no es un **petardo**, ya que en Colombia **petardo** es una carga explosiva que produce daños materiales y físicos y en algunos casos la muerte.

[image]

Una caja de **voladores**:

[image]

Un video que muestra el lanzamiento de un **volador**

[Voladores en la población de Tabio en Colombia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=wTJVVkw0AI4)